# VSTFS 2015: Unable to delete remote branch

Tags: git, tfs, version-control

I have a setup of VSTFS that is 2015 with git. Somehow we have two branches, *Development* which is one I want to keep isolated since that is our master. Somehow there is a remote branch *development* (lower case d) as well. I want to delete this one since it is confusing, but I'm afraid to do so in case we get into issues.

[image]

My problem is, I'm running VS 2017 and it won't delete the remote branch. I did this by right clicking in team explorer and clicking "delete".

[image]

The message from the output window says the following:

> Error encountered while deleting branch from the remote repository: Git process failed unexpectedly.
>   PushCommand.ExecutePushCommand

So, I open up a cli and see what's there. The command here would be to do

```
git branch -d -r origin/<branchname>
```

However, I tried it on another throw away branch, and I'm still able to see it in the TFS listing in the browser.

My question is, how do I delete lower case development to make sure that I don't delete uppercase development?

**UPDATE**:

Seems that I am missing ForcePush permissions on our git instance, despite being a TFS administrator. Currently determining if this is the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update 2:**  There's a great executive summary for how to delete remote branches provided in [this previous stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely).  One thing that's left out I think is that in order to execute the command `$ git push -d <remote_name> <branch_name>` you'll need permissions to "force-push" to the branch.

**Update:** This may be a problem with git's case insensitivity.  See the blog post here:  https://tosbourn.com/git-branches-seem-to-be-case-insensitive/

**Original Answer:** 
I think `git push origin :development` will do it.  You can think of this as "push null to development" -- in other words, delete the branch.

I believe when you execute `git branch -d -r origin/<branch name>` you are only removing your remote tracking branch, which is stored locally.

Comment: Your last update is what did the trick. Despite being an admin for TFS overall, I didn't have "forcePush" permissions on git! This was the issue, and after I got the new permissions it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the deleted branch has chosen as the default branch for the remote repository. You must choose an another default branch for the remote repository in this case.